# Javascript Code Folding by Regions in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, code-folding

I was looking after region based code folding for javascript files in eclipse.
The only thing I could find so far was Coffee Bytes Code Folding which extends the editor folding settings in eclipse.http://market.eclipsesource.com/yoxos/node/com.cb.eclipse.folding.feature.group

Does anyone know something similar for javascript? That would allow me to add a custom identifier for regions such as

// ## region A

code to fold..

// ## region B

code to fold..

Thanks

Comment: Can you create code blocks using curly brackets {} for that? This would not dirty your code with 'folding information' and you can use the Eclipse build-in folding.

Comment: i plan on using it within an MCV framework and wanted to use this approach to collapse everything in my views/controllers besides relevant logic. Since there are multiple devs involved, it doesnt seem to be a good approach to create new code blocks just for my readability convenience

Answer (score 1):

This should work :
(Altough it doesn`t work for me, Version Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1))

Goto top menu >Window > prefrences > javaScript > Editor > Folding > Enable everething